# Difference between "use X to do Y" and "use X for doing Y"

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

- We use algorithm A to solve the problem.
- We use algorithm A for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no a semantic difference between the two sentences. They both have the same meaning.

First sentence uses an infinitive construction: ‘to solve’, while the second contains the preposition ‘for’, usually followed by the noun, that is: ‘solving’.