# What message is conveyed by "He asks if he is allowed to ..."

Tags: difference, questions, phrase-choice, if

I want to know whether the following phrase makes sense

> The letter is about asking permission for eating during the class time.

I asked a native speaker and he answered yes, it is easy to understand, but he also recommended the  following rephrasing:

> The letter asks if students are allowed to eat during the class time.

But I think that these two phrases convey different messages; the student who writes the letter already knows that eating during the class time is banned, but in the second phrase, it seems that he doesn't know it and only ask a question to become aware.
Am I correct?

Comment: If the writer already knows that eating during the class time is banned (but he wants that policy reversed), he could adapt the second version: *The letter asks **that** students **be** allowed to eat during class time* (discard that unwanted article before "class time"). Whatever you do though, you should get rid of ***permission for eating***, because that's not very idiomatic for the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you think about the accepted answer? Is **permission to eat** also non-idiomatic?

Comment: *permission **to** [do something]* is fine, but *permission **for** [doing it]* isn't. That's now at least *three* people who've told you effectively the same thing, but you still seem to be unsure. Have a look at [“To do” or “For doing”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65702/) and [“For doing” vs. “To do”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58801/) and [“To do this” or “For doing this” to start explaining something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84997/) and [Difference between “use X to do Y” and “use X for doing Y”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree with the distinction that you make between your phrasing and the phrasing that the native speaker recommended.

But if the student knows that eating is forbidden, I think that this wording would still be an improvement: "The letter is to ask permission to eat during class time."